# Register Modifier keys for a CustomControl

Tags: c#, winforms, keyboard, keyevent

I am working on a `CustomControl` and I want to register `ModifierKeys` in this control. I have already set the `KeyPerview` to `True` in the `Form` which this control is being added to.

Now I have a `Boolean` named `_ctrl` and I want this boolean to be `true` when the `Control` key is being held down and it should be `false` when `Control` key is being released.

I tried to achive this with the conde belowe in my `CustomControl` but no success!

```
private bool _ctrl = false;

private void MyCustomControl_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if(e.KeyCode == Keys.Control)
    {
        _ctrl = true;
    }
}

private void MyCustomControl_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Control)
    {
        _ctrl = false;
    }
}
```

Any tips/soloution will be appriciated!

**UPDATE**

Ok, I decided to do the key down and up event in the form itself:

```
        private void MainForm_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Modifiers == Keys.Control)
        {
            projectBrowser.ControlKeyIsDown = true; //bool in MyCustomControl
            MessageBox.Show("CTRL is PRESSED");
        } 
     }

    private void MainForm_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Modifiers == Keys.Control)
        {
            projectBrowser.ControlKeyIsDown = false; //bool in MyCustomControl
            MessageBox.Show("CTRL is DEPRESSED");
        } 
    }
```

Now, The KeyDown event detects the control key and messagebox is being shown. But the `KeyUp` event does not work and it doesn't show the messagebox. What could be wrong?

It seems that the key up gets detected if I change the `KeyUp`event like this:

```
private void MainForm_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.LControlKey || e.KeyCode == Keys.RControlKey || e.KeyCode == Keys.ControlKey || e.KeyCode == Keys.Control)
    {
        projectBrowser.ControlKeyIsDown = false;
        e.Handled = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by no success?

Comment: I mean if I put a message box in both events the message box never gets called....it means my soloution is not working!

Comment: Is the focus on your custom control?

Comment: And.. why do you need to keep track of a modifier key? Are you trying to implement a hotkey? Or are you sure doing this is what you want?

Comment: Please check my question update. Yeah I need to know if a key like `Control` is being held down so my program can react to this event.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try calling the `Control.ModifierKeys` property:

```
protected override void OnKeyDown(KeyEventArgs e) {
  if (Control.ModifierKeys == Keys.Control) {
    MessageBox.Show("I am pressing control.");
  }
  base.OnKeyDown(e);
}
```

If you throw up a MessageBox on the KeyDown event, the KeyUp event won't get called.